# $f^{-1}f(L)=L+\text{Ker}f$

Tags: modules, group-homomorphism, inverse-function, quotient-set

Let $f:M \longrightarrow N$ be a module homomorphism and let $L$ be a submodule of $M$. I would like to prove that

$f^{-1}f(L)=L+\text{Ker}f.$

I tried using the first isomorphism theorem, but I cannot write it for the inverse function $f$. Is it the right approach? What is the best way to prove it?

Comment: By the first isomorphism theorem, $N \supset  \text{im}f \cong M/ \ker f$ so elements in $\text{im} f$ are cosets of the form $L + \ker f$. $f^{-1}$ just pulls any element in the image back to its coset.

Comment: @OsamaGhani how can be true that $f^{-1}(L+Kerf) = L+Kerf$? (Perhaps I didn't understand your answer). Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Elements in $M/ \ker f$ are of the form $[L]$ where $[L] = [L']$ if $[L] - [L'] \in \ker f$ i.e. for a *single* element is given by $[L] + \ker f$ which we also treat as a single element. $f$ sends $L$ to $[L] + \ker f$. Now, $f^{-1}$ pulls back this element to the entire coset $L + \ker f$. In particular, two elements have the same preimage if they are in the same coset. Note that $f^{-1}$ isn't even a function so don't call it that, it's a preimage operator. However, restricted to $\text{im} f$ it *is* a bijection between $\text{im} f$ and $M / \ker f$